# Whitespace between words is removed when exporting to PDF

Tags: fonts, spacing, xetex

Viewing the PDF at first glance looks fine (words appear to have space between them).

[Screenshot of  normal looking pdf output]

[image: screenshot of normal looking pdf output]

When copy/pasting the text, however, this happens.
`Performednetwork,web,andoffensivepenetrationtestingforclientcompanies`

Upon closer inspection, there actually aren't any space characters between the words - words just have padding between them. Many companies scan in resumes, which results in them seeing this space-less version.

I'm using this resume template (https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume).

Is there a way to explicitly add spaces to a latex output?

Comment: If you are really using xetex it could be difficult. With luatex it is probably possible.

Comment: Related: [Text copied from pdf is missing spaces, or has extra ones](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/317586) and possible duplicate: [XeLaTeX and missing spaces in PDF text](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/21085)

Comment: Acrobat copied the spaces fine.  One would think that if it affects any PDF resume, it would affect ALL PDF resumes and they would have fixed it.